# SSIS Auto Mapping to OLE DB Destination

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, ssis, etl

I am wondering if a solution to the following problem exists in SSIS.

I have 2 column table (ID and Name fields) that I create a 3rd column for with a SQL script task, called filename. This only is created if the column doesn't already exist. My package is displayed below at both the control at data flow levels.

My package will create the column "Filename" just fine if it doesn't exist, but instead of pulling the name of the file correctly in the loop, it will be all null as the "Filename" wasn't mapped to the destination (as it didn't exist before). I can easily fix this by simply going to the destination and mapping the Filename from the loop to the "Filename" column that was created, but this means I have to re-run the package.

My core question, is there a way for SSIS to automap my variable that contains the filename to the destination column "Filename" that gets created outside the loop? Or do I have to manually map that thing every time I work with a table that didn't have the column in there when I ran the package.

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

Comment: _is there a way for SSIS to automap my variable that contains the filename to the destination column that gets created outside the loop_. No. You could use some kind of a dummy table at design time, and map the column then. At run time, as long as validation is turned off, it might run OK. But next time you edit the package you have to make sure he whole thing is set up correctly. I have to ask: why doesn't the column already permanently exist in the table? Creating columns on the fly rings alarm bells. Databases and integrations really hinge on consistent meta data

Comment: .. and by 'no' I mean 'Yes but i's so convoluted you don't want to do it (using BIML, editing package XML etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your script - always return something. on success return file name on failure return NULL or ''. In this case one time mapping at your OLEDB destination is fine.